# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\dev\jszip-test\node_modules\jszip\lib'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, jszip

I'm using `jszip v3.2.1` in an angular 7 application. When I build my project (running, for example, `npm start`) I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/jszip/lib/readable-stream-browser.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   'C:\dev\jszip-test\node_modules\jszip\lib'

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

After reading [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10625#issuecomment-392634604) post I found out that the stream package was missing from my project.

You can install it by running the following command:

```
npm i stream
```

Comment: it is a bug in "readable-stream" itself, it is missing package stream in the dependencies.

Comment: When I do this, an error message pops up that shows Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined. How to solve (create-react-app, brain.js)

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I wanted to import `EventEmitter` and added it accidentally from `stream` package instead of `@angular/core` package.

Answer (score 5):

This issue encountered when importing web3 to your project. Please follow steps in below article.

https://medium.com/@rasmuscnielsen/how-to-compile-web3-js-in-laravel-mix-6eccb4577666

Fix is:-

Wherever you import the web3 library, change your import from

import Web3 from 'web3'

to
import Web3 from 'web3/dist/web3.min.js'

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this error while building an angular library.

It came from my IDE auto-importing EventEmitter from 'stream' instead of '@angular/core' in the library.

Check for:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "stream";
```

Update to:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your package.json, change react-scripts to 4.0.3 and run yarn / npm install

Comment: This is an angular question, not a react one.