# ERROR ReferenceError: strXmlBullet is not defined - pptxgenjs

Tags: angular8, pptxgenjs

Tried many ways changing tsconfig.json, angular.json but it doesn't work.

Taken ref from below links but didn't get any help.

```
# https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/issues/220
# https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10625
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601669/module-not-found-error-        
cant-resolve-stream-in-c-dev-jszip-test-node-modul
# https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/776
```

I have done following for integration :

```
npm install pptxgenjs
npm install stream

import * as pptGen from 'pptxgenjs';
var pptx = new pptGen();
var slide = pptx.addNewSlide();
slide.addText('Hello World!', { x:1.5, y:1.5, fontSize:18, color:'363636' 
});
pptx.save('Sample Presentation');
```

Answer (score 0):

strXmlBullet is not defined - pptxgenjs

I have reported this bug and Brent got it fix.

https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/issues/587